# Formation of valence and conduction bands from atomic orbitals

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, orbitals

In the wiki article on the [electronic band structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure)[image: this figure] illustrates on how the valence and conduction bands of group 4 semiconductors like diamond emerge from the 2s and 2p orbitals of the C atoms.

Chemistry textbooks as far as I know state that individual C atoms create sp3 hybrid orbitals BEFORE forming bonds to other atoms. If one assumes only a single sp3 orbital widening to a band upon interaction between many atoms, then in the logic of the figure only one band will form without the possibility for a band gap.

Is there a reason why the figure displays the interaction of explicitly 2s and 2p orbitals leading to the band structure? Or are the valence/conduction bands for e.g. diamond rather a result of the interaction between many bonding/anti-bonding [bonding/anti-bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibonding_molecular_orbital) states formed by sp3-sp3 bonds as [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480986/band-formation-in-diamond) suggests? Is there someone around with firmer knowledge than myself to comment on my puzzlement?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278844/why-do-p-orbitals-correspond-to-the-valence-band-in-semiconductors/278999#278999 may be of some relevance. Fundamentally the diagram presented above is hand waving at best, mostly to get you thinking about how atomic energy levels might translate into crystal energy levels. You are not the first person to be confused by them.

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster for pointing to your other answer. Looks like I had false hopes for an intuitive understanding that isn't easily gained. Thanks anyway!